# Unable to get KVM working on Fedora Linux running on a AMD machine

Tags: linux, virtualization, fedora, linux-kvm, amd-ryzen

I have been trying to get KVM working on my Fedora Linux installed on a desktop computer with AMD processor with no success.

```
[kp@localhost ~]$ lscpu | grep svm
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx cpb hw_pstate sme ssbd sev ibpb vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 rdseed adx smap clflushopt sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves clzero irperf xsaveerptr arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif overflow_recov succor smca
```

SVM is available as we can observe in the flags shown above. I also verified in the BIOS settings that the "Secure Virtual Machine" is enabled.

```
[kp@localhost ~]$ lsmod | grep kvm
kvm                   724992  0
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
```

When I try loading kvm_amd module, the command gets stuck for ever:

```
[kp@localhost ~]$ sudo modprobe kvm_amd
[sudo] password for kp:
```

When I try creating a new Virtual machine using Virual Machine Manager, it gives me the following warning:

```
Warning: KVM is not available. This may mean KVM package is not installed, or the KVM kernel modules are not loaded. Your virtual machines may perform poorly.
```

Any ideas of what may be the problem here? I did not find any glaring errors printed in journalctl output.

Comment: which AMD processor?  Is your MB bios up to date?  After enabling SVM, et. al, did you perform a power cycle, not just a soft reboot?

Comment: @essjae AMD Ryzen 7 1700x. Yes, I have updated the MB bios to the latest available. Yes, I did power cycle the machine. In fact I could not find a way to disable SVM in my bios settings, it is enabled by default.

Comment: Just added my findings as a post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much searching on the internet, I found that the problem is that kvm_amd is not active on this Fedora Linux kernel. Apparently one needs to compile the kernel using a custom parameter called CONFIG_CRYPTO_DEV_SP_PSP=n to fix this problem.

Found this information from here:

https://forum.level1techs.com/t/antergos-kvm-amd-not-active-threadripper/130245/9

Check out the post by user IceWind:

"Compiling the kernel with CONFIG_CRYPTO_DEV_SP_PSP=n seems to fix the kvm issue with the latest bios updates on threadripper."

Comment: Can you please either file a bug for this or post to the [kernel mailing list](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/kernel@lists.fedoraproject.org/) so we can make sure this gets addressed?

Comment: Yep, I will try to file a report on this.

Comment: This also worked for me on Arch Linux. I couldn't get KVM to run on newer kernels, but with this change, it worked. Thanks a lot @KeshavPrasad!

Comment: @mattdm If I try sign-in via stackoverflow or any other oauth to kernel mailing list site, it shows errors. If I try to sign up it gives the message that there no new signups allowed. Is there any email address where I can report this problem to?